# Firebase rest api Patch request

Tags: angular, firebase, http, google-cloud-firestore, cors

Hi I'm developing an angular application using firebase, I have to modify the value of a record inside my db and I'm using the rest api:

```
  this.http.patch(fireBaseConfigDBEndpointCloudReference + this.logIn.getUser().value.id, {
            "name": "",
            "fields": {
                "role": {
                    "stringValue": "pending"
                }
            }
        })
```

I get the following error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/project-name/databases/(default)/documents/users/id' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Method PATCH is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Methods in preflight response.

Any idea on how to fix?

Comment: That's your browser telling you that you can't make offsite HTTP requests due to standard security concerns (it will be helpful to read up on CORS to understand this). Probably what you should be doing instead is using the JavaScript client libraries for Firestore.

Comment: The CORS config for the `https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/project-name/databases/(default)/documents/users/id` endpoint needs to be changed to allow PATCH requests. See https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/configuring-cors

Comment: @sideshowbarker thank you, can you please explain me how to configure? I'm a newbie and I don't know where to start from, Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned in the documentation [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS):  `"CORS is a mechanism that uses additional HTTP headers to tell browsers to give a web application running at one origin, access to selected resources from a different origin."`. This means that this is a way to provide more information via browsers from distinct origins.

Considering the error, it seems that yours is configured to not allow for the endpoint PATCH to be executed. Sometimes this occurs because PATCH is an endpoint to perform partial modifications on the resource - more information [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/PATCH).

I would recommend you to check the documentation [Configuring CORS](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/configuring-cors), to find more information about it, regarding the use with GCP.

Let me know if the information helped you!